# Block Sequence Number Input

Tags: javascript, jquery

It should not be possible to enter a sequence of numbers with more than 7 digits, these having spaces or not between the characters.

Example number sequences to block:

`99999999999
99 9 9999 9999
99 9999 9999`

```
<input type="text" name="texto" id="texto"/>

        $('input:text, textarea').keyup(function(){
            var num = $(this).val();
            var a1 = num.split(" ");
            for (i=0;i<a1.length;i++)
            {

                var total_letras = a1[i].length;
                if($.isNumeric(a1[i])){

                        if(total_letras > 7)
                        { 
                            $(this).val( num.substring(0, num.length - 2) );
                            $(this).addClass("input_bloqueado");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $(this).removeClass("input_bloqueado");
                        }

                }
            }
        });
```

That is, if the user enters a sequence of numbers longer than 7 digits, the script must obfuscate or remove these numbers.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? It's not clear what you're asking here.

Comment: That's not a question. That's telling us what it's doing right now. What do you want it to do?

Comment: What do you expect this to do if not erase the white space? `texto.replace(" ","")`

Comment: @Turnip and what is the solution to the case?

Comment: I don't know because it is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Turnip I corrected the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex `/((?:[1-9]\s*){7})/g` or `/((?:\d\s*){7})/g` if you want the number from 0-9.

Demo:

```js
$('#texto').keyup(function(){
    var reg = /((?:[1-9]\s*){7})/g;
    var texto = $(this).val();
    var result = texto.replace(reg,"********") ;

    $("#texto").val( result );
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="texto" id="texto"/>
```